# Laravel Query | How to set OrderBy to a new array?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

i have added a new array to **my elements** like this code :

```
 $elements= Code::get();
 
 foreach($elements as $element){
    $string = str_random(15);
    $element->total = $string; 
 }
```

I would like to return elements after set orderBy() on total using this code

```
return response()->json(['Status'=> '1','Elements' => $elements ]);
```

Thank you and i appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is not how `foreach` works actually. `foreach` creates a "mirror" of your array so doing any insertion on `$element` does not affect your initial array at all.

You need to insert your value directly in your array, so you can either use a counter or simpler a for loop.

I will modify your foreach to stay similar to your approach.

Judging by how you tried to insert the value in your array i assume you have a collection and not an array so if that's the case you can add this line before everything:

```
$elements = $elements->toArray(); //convert collection to array
     $counter = 0;
     foreach($elements as $element){
        $string = str_random(15);
        $elements[$counter]['total'] = $string;
        $counter++;
     }
```

Your `$elements` array now has the field total in each of the nested arrays.

Then you simple do:

```
array_multisort( array_column($elements, "total"), SORT_ASC, $elements);
```

If you want to sort in descending order simple use `SORT_DESC`